# How to sum an output in Python

Tags: python-3.x

The program below will create a list of 100 numbers chosen randomly between    1-10.  I need help to then sum the list, then average the list created.

I have no idea how to begin and since I'm watching videos online I have no person to turn to.  I'm very fresh in this world so I may just be missing entire ideas.  I would doubt that I don't actually know enough though because the videos I paid for are step by step know nothing to know something.

Edit: I was informed that what the program does is overwrite a variable, not make a list. So how do I sum my output like this example?

This is all I have to go on:

[image: all I have to go on]

Code:

```
import random

x=0
while x < 100:
    mylist = (random.randrange(1,10))
    print(mylist) 
    x = x+1
```

Comment: `How to sum an output`... use the `sum` function.

Comment: No it won't create a list, it will override the same variable you called `mylist` again and again with a random number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the shortest and pythonic way to do this is:

```
import random
x = [random.randrange(1,10) for i in range(100)] #list comprehension
summed = sum(x)                                  #Sum of all integers from x
avg = summed / len(x)                            #Average of the numbers from x
```

In this case this shouldn't have a big impact, but you should never use `while` and code manual counter when you know how many times you want to go; in other words, always use `for` when it's possible. It's more efficient and clearer to see what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(list):
    sm = 0
    for i in list:
        sm+=i
    return sm
```

Just run `sum(list)` to get sum of all elements

Or you can use

```
import random
x=0
mylist = []
sm = 0
while x < 100:
     mylist.append(random.randrange(1,10))
     sm += mylist[x]
     x += 1
```

Then sm will be sum of list

Answer (score 0):

The code is not correct. It will not create a list but generate a number everytime. Use the below code to get your desired result.

```
import random
mylist = []
for x in range(100):
    mylist.append(random.randrange(1,10))
print(mylist)   
print(sum(mylist))
```

OR

```
import random
mylist = [random.randrange(1,10) for value in range(100)]
print(mylist)   
print(sum(mylist))
```

Output:

```
[3, 9, 3, 1, 3, 5, 8, 8, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 2, 4,
 6, 9, 7, 9, 5, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9, 2, 5, 8, 2, 4, 3, 8, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2,
 2, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2, 1, 9, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 5, 7, 9, 4, 9, 8, 
 7, 5, 9, 2, 6, 8, 8, 3, 4, 8, 4, 7, 9, 9, 4, 2, 9, 9, 6, 3, 4, 9, 5, 
 3, 8, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 6]

 512
```

Comment: List comprehension is better.